# Selector won't work if concatenated to view controller swift

Tags: swift, string, function, selector

I tried to create a setupTap function which gets as an argument a string, which should be a function name. When in the selector I try to call the function (Function's view controller concatenated with the function string name) it won't work. This is what I have tried:

```
func setupTap(functionName: String) {
    let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: MainScreenViewController().perform(NSSelectorFromString(functionName)))
    settingLabel.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    settingLabel.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
}
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By doing this:

```
MainScreenViewController().perform(NSSelectorFromString(functionName))
```

You are not passing a selector, you are performing a selector straight away. You should let the gesture recogniser do the performing of selectors.

In fact, swift has this cool syntax of creating selectors:

```
#selector(someFunc)
```

It does not use any string literals, so there is a compile time checking for typos!

Your `setupTap` function should be like this:

```
func setupTap(selector: Selector) {
    let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: selector)
    settingLabel.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    settingLabel.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
}
```

Call this like this:

```
setupTap(selector: #selector(someFunc))
```

Comment: This has indeed worked perfectly. Thanks for you help!